# Regex matching whole line starting with an exclamation mark

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to match whole line of text starting from `!` 
with regex.

I made something like this: `/(!\w+\s+\S+)/ig` which is pretty close, but only for 2 words. I would like to match words upto new line. Also I see problem with spoiler in the middle of sentence.

Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/MXmholsDwE

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You just need

```
^!.*
```

See the [updated regex demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/84wAzTZz42)

The `^` matches the start of a line (in Ruby), `!` will match a literal `!` and `.*` will match zero or more characters other than a newline (if you are using Ruby, which I assume from your use of the rubular Web site).

If you are using a regex flavor other than Ruby, like JS, or PHP, or .NET, you need to specify the `/m` - MULTILINE - modifier (e.g. `/^!.*/gm` in JavaScript).

Comment: Working like a charm :), but one thing - need to add <br> exception so: `^!.[^<]*`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match everything to the end of the line:

```
/(!.+)/
```

If you want to make sure that it follows the format `!word---`:

```
/!\w.+/
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be.

```
^!\b.*$
```

Where

> `^` Start of line

> `!` Match starting

> `\b.*$` rest of line till end

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an exception for `<br>` you should use a positive look-ahead operator. Please also note that parsing an HTML document using regex is usually not a good thing to do.

I think you should consider `<br />` also. So, final reg-ex would be:

```
^!.+?(?=\<br\>|\<br\s*\/\>|$)
```

It will match highlighted portions of the sample below:

> **!spoiler sample** 
>   no spoiler 
>   **!spoiler** 
>   **!spoiler with more** <br> words 
>   **!spoiler upto new** <br /> line 
>   
>   spoiler in the !middle of sentence

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/nZ0oY9/3

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.+` regex with the `global` flag to match separate whole lines. Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
^![^\n]*
```

Explanation:

`^` - beginning of a string

`!` - match `!` literally

`[^\n]*` - match zero or more character other than newline

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3wLAy0/1)

[Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/jtmL1BXYhWCxia)